# Local start and end of day in UTC

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

I would like to find out what the start and end time of a specific day is expressed in UTC and in Python.

For instance:

- the current date and time is Sun 29 Oct 2023, 01:33:49 CEST (Central European Summer Time),
- the day starts at Sun 29 Oct 2023, 00:00:00 CEST,
- the day ends at Sun 29 Oct 2023, 23:59:59 CET (NB, the time zone switched from CEST (daylight saving time) to CET (not on daylight saving time))

Now I would like to get these times in UTC:

- Start: Sat 28 Oct 2023, 22:00:00 UTC
- End: Sun 29 Oct 2023, 22:59:59 UTC (the day contains 25 hours)

I do not want to set the timezone programatically - I want to get it from my system.

I find this easy to do in Swift as every date is timezone aware, but I can't get my head around on how to do this in Python. The reason why I need to do this is because I want to get all the data within a specific (local) day from my database, which contains UTC timestamps.

I've tried this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, time
import pytz

start_of_day = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), time.min)
end_of_day = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), time.max)
print(start_of_day) 
print(end_of_day) 
print(start_of_day.astimezone().tzinfo)
print(end_of_day.astimezone().tzinfo)

start_of_day = pytz.utc.localize(start_of_day)
end_of_day = pytz.utc.localize(end_of_day)
print(start_of_day) 
print(end_of_day) 
print(start_of_day.astimezone().tzinfo)
print(end_of_day.astimezone().tzinfo)
```

which gives the following output:

```
2023-10-29 00:00:00
2023-10-29 23:59:59.999999
BST
GMT
2023-10-29 00:00:00+00:00
2023-10-29 23:59:59.999999+00:00
BST
GMT
```

while I would expect, something like (I guess UTC might also be GMT):

```
2023-10-29 00:00:00
2023-10-29 23:59:59.999999
CEST
CET
2023-10-28 22:00:00+00:00
2023-10-29 22:59:59.999999+00:00
UTC
UTC
```

Not only are the times wrong, but the timezones are also weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pytz's `localize` just sets the time zone, it doesn't convert like `astimezone` does.

Here's a slightly modified version of your code. We can use the standard lib datetime.timezone.utc to set UTC, to make things a bit clearer (pytz is deprecated since Python 3.9 btw.). See also comments in the code for some explanation.

```py
from datetime import datetime, time, timezone

start_of_day = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), time.min)
end_of_day = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), time.max)
print(start_of_day) # naive datetime here...
print(end_of_day) 
print(start_of_day.astimezone().tzinfo)
print(end_of_day.astimezone().tzinfo)

start_of_day = start_of_day.astimezone(timezone.utc) # convert / make aware, UTC
end_of_day = end_of_day.astimezone(timezone.utc)
print(start_of_day) 
print(end_of_day) 
print(start_of_day.tzinfo) # datetime object is already aware here, no need for astimezone
print(end_of_day.tzinfo)
```

On my system that is configured to use time zone "Europe/Berlin" the output is

```
2023-10-29 00:00:00 # naive datetime, but "silently" on UTC+2
2023-10-29 23:59:59.999999 # same but UTC+1
CEST
CET
# Note that the conversion from local to UTC applies the UTC offset:
2023-10-28 22:00:00+00:00 # was on UTC+2, so clock moves back 2h for UTC
2023-10-29 22:59:59.999999+00:00 # was UTC+1, clock back 1h
UTC
UTC
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected. The timezone was still wrong because apparently I had set it incorrectly on the raspberry pi and didn't fully realise I was working remotely - the timezone was of course correct on my dev computer.

Comment: @Dieudonné glad I could help. The thing with the second part of your code is, if you call `start_of_day.astimezone().tzinfo`, you're effectively converting to the local tz, not matter if the input is tz-aware or naive. That's why the output was "BST" / "GMT" for both the first and the second part.